# How to join tables where you need to select from table you are joining with

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm very new to SQL!
I want to keep some columns from table 1 and join the keys in table 1 (AccountStatusID) and table 2 (StatusID) to obtain information (Status) from table 2.

So I have two queries that gives me what I want:

```
SELECT 
[Account Number] = AccountNumber,
[Account Name] = PrimaryClientFullName,
[Date Created] = DateSubmitted,
[Date Closed] = CloseDateTime, 
[Dast Last Active] = DateTimeCurrentStatus,
[Date Completed] = DateTimeCompleted,
[Account Status] = AccountStatusID
FROM Table1
WHERE InternalUse = '1'
```

AND

```
SELECT Status
FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON StatusID = AccountStatusID
```

The separate queries give me what I want. I get the 7 columns in the first query and the last column with the description I want in the second query. I just want to combine them together into one.

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it !!!!

Comment: Did you try adding the left join to the first query? Did that work? What didn't work about it?

Comment: The description is in the second table so when I add "LEFT JOIN Table2 ON AccountStatusID = StatusID" to the first query, I would just get the keys because I didn't select Status (the descriptions) in the beginning. I don't know how to add "SELECT Status from table2"  into the first query when I have SELECT .... FROM Table 1

Comment: You just add the left join of Table2, and add the Status column to the list of columns to return. Try it out.

Comment: I feel silly that works !! Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
  [Account Number] = AccountNumber,
  [Account Name] = PrimaryClientFullName,
  [Date Created] = DateSubmitted,
  [Date Closed] = CloseDateTime, 
  [Dast Last Active] = DateTimeCurrentStatus,
  [Date Completed] = DateTimeCompleted,
  [Account Status] = AccountStatusID,
  [Status] = AccountStatus
FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON StatusID = AccountStatusID
WHERE InternalUse = '1'
```